# I keep getting "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.29:8080 " On postman console while im trying to make a get request on sts4

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, crud, rest

I have been trying all possible urls but same error keeps showing. please help. thanks in advance

here is my controller

```html
package com.springstad.stad.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springstad.stad.entitites.Names;
import com.springstad.stad.services.NameService;
@RestController

public class MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    
    private NameService nameservice;
    // get employee names
    @RequestMapping(path="/Names",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    
    public List<Names> getNames(){
        
        return this.nameservice.getNames();
        
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path="/names/{nameID}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    
    public Names getNames(@PathVariable("nameID") String nameID) {
        return this.nameservice.getNames(Long.parseLong(nameID));
    }
}
```

what proxy config must i do for the postman to get responses from the code? ive been using localhost:8080/Names as url

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its Spring-Boot app, pls check for servlet: context-path in application.yml (or application.properties). Lets say its value is "app1", then try with following url

localhost:8080/app1/Names